# android build is failed. React Native

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings